# error The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql, jboss

Estoy llamando a un procedure desde una pagina, cada vez que lo llamo obtengo este error en consola

```
09:34:08,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) 20/04/2017 
09:34:08.941 INFO  projectX:ReportRankingPointsMB:searchReport:86 - [UserId: 210] searchReport() SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1449];   
09:34:08,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- The error occurred in com/ivision/dao/sqlMapPointsCashlessDB.xml.  
09:34:08,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
09:34:08,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Check the points.getPointsRankingByParameter-InlineParameterMap.  
09:34:08,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Check the statement (update procedure failed).  
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- The error occurred in com/ivision/dao/sqlMapPointsCashlessDB.xml.  
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Check the points.getPointsRankingByParameter-InlineParameterMap.  
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Check the statement (update procedure failed).  
09:34:08,943 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) --- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist
```

Estoy usando jboss eap 6.x como servidor y configure el standalone, no tengo problemas al realizar otras consultas, hay alguna manera de que pueda solucionar este error?

no puedo modificar permisos de usuarios ya que ese el unico acceso que tengo a db, ademas tampoco estoy usando ningun usuario root ni en mi proyecto ni en el standalone lo cual me parece muy raro

Comment: El usuario que creó la procedure en la bd no existe, de ahí el error. [Ver esta pregunta de enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: ya la vi, pero el hecho es que soy un usuario mas de la DB mas no el administrador, podria hacer esa modificacion  para que funcione aun no siendo el admin?

Comment: Eso dependerá de los derechos que tengas como usuario. Puedes ser otro usuario con privilegios de administrador, si es así podrías hacer los cambios. O bien escribir tu propia procedure.

Comment: si tengo todos los privilegios salvo por uno, que es el de "Grant_privileges", que puedo hacer?

Comment: Se podría cambiar, pero por seguridad, es mejor que lo consultes con el administrador de la BD, él  sabrá cómo hacerlo de la mejor manera.

Comment: vale, pero lo mas raro es que al revisar la lista de usuarios en esa DB ese usuario  **root**   si existe, de hecho hay 3 de ellos con diferente contraseña, hay alguna solucion alternativa en este caso?