# Error: The user specied as a definer ('Admin'@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Error de SQL (1449): The user specied as a definer ('Admin'@'%') does not exist

> Tengo un error cuando intento actualizar un registro de una tabla de la base de datos, el problema es que sólo pasa con esa tabla, he realizado esta consulta en la base de datos
>
> Consulta-SQL:

```
show procedure status
```

> Pero cuando hago la consulta no me muestra mi base de datos, ¿qué debo hacer sin dañar la base de datos y sin que afecte a las otrasd tablas?

Comment: El usuario que creó la procedure en la base de dato no existe, por eso te da error. [Mira la respuesta en SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64203/error-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-root-does-not-exist)

Comment: Y te recomiendo que visites el siguente enlace [Como hacer una buena preguna](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)